# Microsoft FTP 7.5 server not translating line feeds

Tags: ftp, ascii

I have a file created in Linux that I'm sending out of a MS FTP 7.5 server.  The receiving system (client) is a mainframe.  The file has LF line endings.  The FTP server is not reading those and translating them, so it's not getting transmitted properly.  Is there a way to solve this (other than translating the file)?

Comment: My situation is very much like [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bit.listserv.ibm-main/moWKUI3_Vfw).

Comment: For clarification -From the Windows server to the mainframe are you pushing the file or is the mainframe logging in to the Windows server to pull the file?

Comment: The mainframe is the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture an answer here but take it with a grain of salt as it has been a while since I've done plain FTP on a mainframe... IIRC correctly, when Z/OS does a translation, it fully expects a windows-style line ending of 0D0A

Run the file through unix2dos (if you have it) on the Linux box, which should convert all of your line-endings to 0D0A and then push the file to your Windows server. Alternatively, you can probably create a test file in notepad in Windows and try it that way...

Then, have the mainframe folks try pulling the file.

See [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.halz001/sbsend.htm) - specifically the Parameters:CRLF and the Rule parts.